# How to get the last element of an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Example:

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 3, 1, 5, 6]
```

How do I get the last value `5` in array `a` or last value `6` in array `b` without using `a[3]` and `b[4]`?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Use `-1` index (negative indices count backward from the end of the array):

```
a[-1] # => 5
b[-1] # => 6
```

or [`Array#last`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last) method:

```
a.last # => 5
b.last # => 6
```

Comment: Let's not forget the convenient `Array#last`, too :) `[1,2,3].last #=> 3`

Comment: @theTinMan Since pop also modifies the array, it's not what was asked for here.

Comment: Also that while 
`a.last = 10 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method last='` 
but 
`a[-1] = 10` works as intended.

Answer (score 13):

One other way, using the splat operator:

```
*a, last = [1, 3, 4, 5]

a => [1, 3, 4]
last => 5
```